# Google App Script GAS - How can I get an <input type="file"> from a form

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, form-submit

I am working on a small project where I have an html form on a website and I wanna use google app script (GAS) for get all form input data and send it into an email address.

So far my code works pretty well; However, I have problem to get the file from my  on my html page

**Here is the code I am using on GAS**

```
function doPost(request) {
  var fname = request.parameters.txtName, femail = request.parameters.txtEmail, fnote = request.parameters.txtArea, ffile = request.parameters.fFileAttach;

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "me@EmailAddress.com",
    subject: "Message from webform by: " + femail,
    htmlBody: "This message was sent by the user " + fname + "<br/>" +
    "User email address: " + femail + "<br />" +
    "Email message:<br/>" + fnote,
    replyTo: femail,
    attachments: [ffile]
  });
}
```

**Here is my html form code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  <form action="myGAS_Link" id="cc-form" method="post">
  <div class="fTop">
    <span>Name:* </span><input name="txtName" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" id="fname" required="" autofocus>
    <span>E-Mail:* </span><input name="txtEmail" type="email" placeholder="Your e-Mail" id="femail" required="">
  </div>
  <!--------------------------->
  <div class="fSet1">
    <span>Notes:</span><br/>
    <textarea name="txtArea" id="fTextArea" rows="8"></textarea>
  </div>
  <!--------------------------->
  <div class="fSub">
   <span>Upload your File:* </span><input name="fFileAttach" id="fFileAttach" type="file" required>
   <input id="submit" type="submit">
  </div>
 </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification?

### Modification points :

#### About HTML

1. Using `FileReader()`, retrieve base64 encoded file, filename and mimetype.
2. Add `input` with `type="hidden"` to `#cc-form` as text data. `replace(/^.*,/, '')` is used for removing a header of encoded data. `match(/^.*(?=;)/)[0]` is used for retrieving mimetype of uploading file.
3. When a submit button is clicked, the base64 data is sent to GAS.

#### About GAS

1. Retrieve data, filename and mimetype as `request.parameters.data`, `request.parameters.filename` and `request.parameters.mimetype`, respectively.
2. Decode the data using `Utilities.base64Decode()`.
3. Create blob using `Utilities.newBlob()`.
4. Import the blob as an attachment file.

### Modified GAS :

```
function doPost(request) {
  var data = Utilities.base64Decode(request.parameters.data); // Added
  var ffile = Utilities.newBlob(data, request.parameters.mimetype, request.parameters.filename); // Added

  var fname = request.parameters.txtName, femail = request.parameters.txtEmail, fnote = request.parameters.txtArea; // Modified

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "me@EmailAddress.com",
    subject: "Message from webform by: " + femail,
    htmlBody: "This message was sent by the user " + fname + "<br/>" +
    "User email address: " + femail + "<br />" +
    "Email message:<br/>" + fnote,
    replyTo: femail,
    attachments: [ffile]
  });

    return ContentService.createTextOutput("ok"); // Added
}
```

### Modified HTML : (Updated)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js"></script> <!-- Added -->
  </head>
  <body>
  <form action="myGAS_Link" id="cc-form" method="post">
  <div class="fTop">
    <span>Name:* </span><input name="txtName" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" id="fname" required="" autofocus>
    <span>E-Mail:* </span><input name="txtEmail" type="email" placeholder="Your e-Mail" id="femail" required="">
  </div>
  <!--------------------------->
  <div class="fSet1">
    <span>Notes:</span><br/>
    <textarea name="txtArea" id="fTextArea" rows="8"></textarea>
  </div>
  <!--------------------------->
  <div id="data"></div> <!-- Added -->
  <div class="fSub">
   <span>Upload your File:* </span><input name="fFileAttach" id="fFileAttach" type="file" required>
   <input id="submit" type="submit">
  </div>
 </form>
  </body>

<!-- Added -->
<script>
$('#fFileAttach').on("change", function() {
    var file = this.files[0];
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.fileName = file.name;
    fr.onload = function(e) {
        html = '<input type="hidden" name="data" value="'+e.target.result.replace(/^.*,/, '')+'" >';
        html += '<input type="hidden" name="filename" value="'+e.target.fileName+'" >';
        html += '<input type="hidden" name="mimetype" value="' + e.target.result.match(/^.*(?=;)/)[0] + '" >';
        $("#data").empty().append(html); // Modified
    }
    fr.readAsDataURL(file);
});
</script>

</html>
```

### Note :

- In order to use this, after the script is modified, please redeploy Web Apps as a new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to Web Apps.
- This sample script can upload one file. If you want to upload several files, please modify script. `var file = this.files[0];` means the selected first file. When there are some files, it is `files[1], files[2] ...`.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

### Edit :

- Your additional question was reflected to the sample script.

  - Added `<div id="data"></div>`
  - Modified from `$("#cc-form").append(html);` to `$("#data").empty().append(html);`

By these modifications, the last selected file is uploaded.

Comment: YES!!!, thank you very much!!
I have 2 months on this without any success. I was on GAS Documentation for so long but you made it look so easy!
Thank you again!!

Comment: @Melvin Guerrero Welcome. I'm glad This is useful for you. Thank you, too.

Comment: I have a question? how can I do to upload just one file?
I am asking this, because I have a little problem with the data, filename, and mimetype hidden inputs.

What is happen is... If I select one file by mistake and select again the right one then the code create another new data, filename and mimetype inputs

Comment: @Melvin Guerrero I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I updated my answer. Please confirm it. Is my understanding of your additional question correct?

Comment: @Melvin Guerrero Welcome. Thank you, too.